# How can I enter Greek numerals based on obsolete letters {Ϛ΄, Ϟ΄, Ϡ΄}?

Tags: macos, keyboard

These three letters, now otherwise obsolete in the Greek language, still have usage in the Greek numeral system:

- 6 = Ϛ΄ (stigma)
- 90 = Ϟ΄ (qoppa)
- 900 = Ϡ΄ (sampi)

Aside from copy-pasting, how can I input these symbols using the Greek Input Source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the Greek Polytonic input source provided by Apple on the option and option-shift levels?

Otherwise the usual way to enter archaic characters is via the [character viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/10.14/mac/10.14).

If you need them often, you can make a text replacement entry in system preferences > keyboard > text > replace with.

If Greek Polytonic doesn't have everything you need, you can make a custom layout with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).